# Android multiple request with facebook graphrequest

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get the facebook friends who are using my app and their cover picture (url) as well. Is there a way for do in one request both, or should I do a separate GraphRequest for each friend in order to obtain his/her cover picture. Now I have :

```
private String[] getUserContacts(){

    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray rawContactsData = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                        contacts=new String[rawContactsData.length()];
                        for (int j = 0; j < rawContactsData.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject item = rawContactsData.getJSONObject(j);
                            contacts[j]=item.getString("id");
                        }
                        Log.d("Contacts","ala"+response);
                        getCalendarData();
                    }catch (JSONException e){

                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();

    return contacts;
}
```

which just provide my with the "name" and the "id" of my friends.

My permissions are

```
facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends, user_photos," +
            "user_posts"));
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem because you need the name of the user in order to add after the fields  `.../fields=<first-level>{<second-level>}`

Comment: If you’re not doing a nested request already, you can simply ask for the field using the `fields` parameter. Basically the same as the example here shows (except that you don’t want a `newMeRequest`, but just a normal one) – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata